# A for loop through dates for daily OLS regressions

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I am trying to run an OLS regression on a daily basis for the Y against X as depicted below. The period is between Jan 2008 to Dec 2011. The idea is to get the daily parameters from which volatility will be inferred. I have managed to run regressions for the first day but the other days are seemingly taking on values from the first day. Since the observations per day are not the same, its difficult since I am a newbie here.

Kindly help me rectify the code below.

```
import statsmodels.api as sm`
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols`

##groupby by index date to enable recursive regressions by day

Kempf_etal2015_model = np.zeros((1,5))`
intercept = np.zeros((1,1))`
betas = np.zeros((1,4))`
for idx, day in df_fp.groupby(df_fp.index.date):`
#     for i in   (day):
    for i in range(len(day)) :

        for j in range(len(df_fp)):
            spreadlag1 = df_fp['relative_spread'].shift(-1)
            c_spreeeed = df_fp['relative_spread'] - df_fp['relative_spread'].shift(-1)
            c_spreeeed_lag1 = df_fp['relative_spread'] - df_fp['relative_spread'].shift(-2)
            c_spreeeed_lag2 = df_fp['relative_spread'] - df_fp['relative_spread'].shift(-3)
            c_spreeeed_lag3 = df_fp['relative_spread'] - df_fp['relative_spread'].shift(-4)
    
            Kempf_etal2015_model = ols('c_spreeeed ~spreadlag1+c_spreeeed_lag1+c_spreeeed_lag2+c_spreeeed_lag3', df_fp).fit()
            intercept =Kempf_etal2015_model.params[:0]
            betas = Kempf_etal2015_model.params[1:]
            print(Kempf_etal2015_model.params)
```

I end up getting the below results

```
Intercept          0.000102
spreadlag1        -0.104292
c_spreeeed_lag1    0.430733
c_spreeeed_lag2    0.020808
c_spreeeed_lag3    0.072575
dtype: float64
Intercept          0.000102
spreadlag1        -0.104292
c_spreeeed_lag1    0.430733
c_spreeeed_lag2    0.020808
c_spreeeed_lag3    0.072575
dtype: float64
```

Comment: What is your question?  How can I test this code?

Comment: Let me share the whole code Scott.

Comment: My question is how can I be able to loop through the different dates (dates have different observations) and then run ols regressions and store the parameters and coefficients separately?

Comment: The link to the whole code is here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tUvHvaFmeJvA2Tk8GifNaTJXAzHad-wC&authuser=ronald.wafula%40ucdconnect.ie&usp=drive_fs and the data is also available here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UoutTWYGfHVTkAS9Ko-xEODqmftZ0KCY&authuser=ronald.wafula%40ucdconnect.ie&usp=drive_fs